# Determine square of distance between local maxima and local minima

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

*P(x)* is a polynomial of degree three having local maxima at x = -1 and given *P(-1)* = 10, *P(1)* = -6. Further *P'(x)* has local minima at x = 1. Determine square of distance between local maxima and local minima.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Is the definition of distance different than the distance on cartesian plane? If you can show what you have done till now and where you got stuck, it will be better.

Comment: The crux of this problem is to reconstruct what polynomial $P(x)$ is.  Then we can fully determine what the local maxima and minima points are.  I would assume that by "distance between local maxima and local minima" the Reader is meant to find distance between two points (rather than perhaps the distance between the arguments or the values at these extrema).  Since a cubic polynomial has at most one local maximum and one local minimum, it would be clearer to state the problem in those terms (maxima and minima are plural nouns).

Comment: The question asks to find the difference of square between the local maximum value and the local minimum value.

Comment: You have four conditions, which is enough information to find the four coefficients of the cubic. The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: You could assume a general cubic polynomial and use the above conditions to form four equations in four variable which are the cofficients polynomial.

Comment: Ya, I got P(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 - 9x + 5 . But the difference of squares of maxima and minima I get is 69 which is a miles away from the options which are : a.) 641 b.) 643 c.) 541 d.) 640

Comment: How you got 69 as difference? The local maximum is achieved at $x=-1$, $P(-1)=10$ and local minimum at $x=3$, $P(3)=-22$. The difference of squares of maxima and minima comes out to be 384.

Comment: Ohh yes... I did a calculation mistake but still, it doesn't seem to match any options.